# React Native- image wont fill screen?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

This is frustrating. I have an image the exact same dimensions as the screen (of this device) and moreover same dimensions as the splash image. I just want it to fill the whole screen, above the other Views, for a few seconds after the splash goes away in order to do a custom animation.

Looking at other SO questions, Ive tried this so far (outside the main container of other app elements):

```
<Animated.View style = {styles.splash}>
          <Image style = {{resizeMode: 'cover'}} source={require('./assets/splash2-txt.png')}/>
        </Animated.View>

splash: {
        flex: 1,
        position: 'absolute',
        zIndex: 4
      },
```

and yet the image is scaled up and way off to the corner.
What is wrong here / how can I just fill the screen with the image?

Comment: Try a [background image](https://reactnative.dev/docs/imagebackground) with [absolute fill](https://reactnative.dev/docs/stylesheet#absolutefill). Is this in the root view?

Comment: @zero298 any idea why this happens? I love a solution but for something like this where there's really strange, inconsistent styling behavior it's best to understand the why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject` in your image style instead of `flex`.

It should be something like...

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Image, View, StyleSheet, StatusBar } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
    <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" />
      <Image style={styles.image} source={{uri: 'https://reactjs.org/logo-og.png'}} />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  image: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
    resizeMode: 'cover',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Please use react-native `ImageBackground` for filling image in background, refer the example code given below

```
import React from "react";
    import { ImageBackground, StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
    
    const image = { uri: "https://reactjs.org/logo-og.png" };
    
    const App = () => (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ImageBackground source={image} style={styles.image}>
          <Text style={styles.text}>Inside</Text>
        </ImageBackground>
      </View>
    );
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: "column"
      },
      image: {
        flex: 1,
        resizeMode: "cover",
        justifyContent: "center"
      },
      text: {
        color: "grey",
        fontSize: 30,
        fontWeight: "bold"
      }
    });
    
    export default App;
```

Comment: I need to animate this image separate from the rest of the app elements though - so it can't be the parent of the rest of the elements; rather, it needs to be overlayed on top